# how to post textarea value into database

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I'm having trouble with posting values typed into `textarea`. everything else works well, any idea how to make it work?

**HTML**:

```
<form id="formData2" action="artistuploader.php" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000"></input>
        <br/>
        <input id="inputField" type="text" name="actname" placeholder="Act Name" >
        <br>
        <input id="inputField" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" >
        <br>
        <input id="inputField" type="text" name="genre" placeholder="Genre" >
        <br>
        <textarea id="inputField" name="biography" form="formData2" placeholder="Biography"<?php echo $biography; ?>></textarea>
        <br>
        <input id="inputField" type="file" name="artistImage" placeholder="Artwork" >
        <br>
        <input id="inputField" type="text" name="imagepath" placeholder="Image path URL" >
        <br>
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="uploadArtist" value="Register Artist">

    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$msg = "";

//if Upload button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['uploadArtist'])){
    $target = "uploads/artistPics".basename($_FILES['artistImage']['name']);


    //connecting to our database
    $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass", "tablename");
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['artistImage']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['artistImage']['name'];
    //getting the submitted form data
    $ActName = $_POST['actname'];
    $FullName = $_POST['fullname'];
    $Genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $ArtistPhoto = $_FILES['artistImage']['name'];
    $imageURLpath = $_POST['imagepath'];
    $Biography = $_POST['biography'];//having problem with this line here

    //saving submitted data into database table songsDB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  artistsdb (ActName,FullName,Genre,ArtistPhoto,Biography,imageURLpath) VALUES ('$ActName','$FullName','$Genre','$ArtistPhoto','$Biography','$imageURLpath')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql); //stores the submitted data into table

    //now moving the uploaded image to uploads folder
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['artistImage']['tmp_name'], $target)){
        $msg = "Uploaded Successful";
    }else{
        $msg = "There was a problem uploading Data";
    }
}

//header("refresh:1; url=index.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Show artistuploader.php. Because there is where it happens.

Comment: hi,  my bad,ive pasted the code, please check again. thanks

Comment: Where have you set the variable $biography that you are outputting in textarea?

Comment: im new to php, this is my attempt of piecing it up together. so do i have to set a variable "biography" to make it work? im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Then please go along and read some tutorials about it. Your code is open for [SQL vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: im asking for help mate and you are telling me to go read about it, but anyway thanks.

Comment: It depends on you if you want to set any value to textarea than you can. Or you may check it like this `<?php echo isset($biography) ? $biography : ''; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `textarea` with

```
 <textarea id="inputField" name="biography" form="formData2" placeholder="Biography"><?php echo $biography; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: hi, i replaced the textarea, and issue persisted,

Comment: the browser says theres an issue with this line in my PHP,
$Biography = $_POST['biography'];

Comment: I think the issue is with `$biography` variable that you are outputting in `textarea`. replace it with `<?php echo isset($biography) ? $biography : ''; ?>`